# Which Django tags are allowed in GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Is there a list of all the tags which are allowed in Google App Engine? I believe it is a subset of the [full Django tag list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/)

for instance

```
{% for  %}
{% endfor %}
```

is allowed but

```
{% with %}
{% endwith %}
```

is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine doesn't restrict what Django tags you can use, although the Python 2.5 runtime does default to using version 0.96 of Django, which is quite old and is missing many of the tags. You can select a newer django version; see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

Comment: yes I've inherited a 0.96 project and this is the link I need
http://django096docs.appspot.com/templates.html